# View foreign key constraints so I can delete a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key, constraint, metadata

I have copied a database I was working on so I could change some key elements of its design for my new version.

I want to delete totally some tables from the database however I cannot due to some foreign key constraints.

1) How can I view the foreign key constraints that exist on a table?

2) How can I delete the foreign keys and the table?

I am viewing this doc for 2008R2 but I am not understanding it [sys.foreign_keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you explain what part(s) you don't understand, so people answering can fill in the gaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And here's how to generate the script @Shark showed for all the tables you want to drop. Let's say you have the following tables:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.z(z INT PRIMARY KEY); -- we won't delete this one

CREATE TABLE dbo.a
(
 a INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.z(z)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.b
(
 b INT PRIMARY KEY, 
 a INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.a(a)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.c
(
 c INT PRIMARY KEY, 
 b INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.b(b), 
 a INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.a(a)
);

-- we won't drop this table either, but we'll need to drop
-- the constraint:

CREATE TABLE dbo.d
(
 d INT, 
 c INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.c(c)
);
```

But we only want to delete a, b, and c.

```
-- load the tables you want to delete into a table variable:

DECLARE @tables_to_delete TABLE (t NVARCHAR(512));

INSERT @tables_to_delete VALUES('dbo.a'),('dbo.b'),('dbo.c');


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

-- build a list of the foreign keys you'll have to drop first:

SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'ALTER TABLE ' 
    + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(f.parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id))
    + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(f.name) + ';'
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN @tables_to_delete AS t
ON f.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(t.t);

-- then the DROP TABLE commands:

SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'DROP TABLE '
    + t + ';'
FROM @tables_to_delete;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Result (the constraint names will look different if you run this):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[b] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__b__a__2D27B809];
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[c] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__c__a__30F848ED];
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[c] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__c__b__300424B4];
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[d] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__d__c__32E0915F];
DROP TABLE dbo.a;
DROP TABLE dbo.b;
DROP TABLE dbo.c;
```

When you're happy about the result, uncomment the `EXEC` line.

(Note, you won't be able to validate the script in its entirety when using `PRINT` if the script is very large. The script is truncated by Management Studio because it still has an archaic limit to how many characters it will show. The string *won't* be truncated like this when it gets passed to `sp_executesql`.)

Answer (score 8):

This first query will get your foreign key constraints for your database, as well as the owning table and the referenced table:

```
select 
    name as FkName,
    object_name(parent_object_id) as ReferencingTable,
    object_name(referenced_object_id) as ReferencedTable
from sys.foreign_keys
```

If you want to drop a FK constraint, you'd do something like this:

```
alter table ChildTable
drop FK_ChildTable_RootTable_RootId
go
```

**WARNING:  Once you drop a foreign key constraint, that will destroy the referential integrity between the two tables.  Do so carefully...**

Comment: +1 when trying to drop a single table this is obviously the easiest approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're trying to get rid of a table that's referenced by other tables (i.e., foreign key constraints exist in other tables that reference the table you're trying to remove).

To do this, right-click on the table in Object Explorer, and click the View Dependencies menu item.

The dialog box will show you which objects reference that table, including both schemabound and non-schemabound dependencies. You can then go to the referenced tables and remove the constraints.